# Boot Camp / macOS Mojave / 3 TB Fusion drive

Tags: bootcamp, startup

If I replace the current 3 TB hard drive with a compatible SSD drive, will this fix the issue with being able to load and run boot camp on my 2012 iMac?

- [If you see the alert 'Installation cannot proceed with Boot Camp configured'](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT209057)

Comment: @Russell: The link you gave did not say you could not install and run Windows. The link just says you can not use Boot Camp to *install* Windows. Have you tried installing Windows 10 after upgrading to Mojave?

Comment: So basically the question is: Does changing the 3TB drive to an SDD allow me to use Bootcamp to install Windows, right?

Answer (score -1):

Bootcamp isn't dependent on the type of drive that you use.

What matters is it's hardware compatability with the Windows version you want to run.

Comment: yes but I cannot even get boot camp to start as I have the 3tb fusion drive now and all the blogs I have read seem to think it is specific to that drive.

Comment: Also, I had boot camp up and running before Mojave with windows 10 installed and it worked great.

Comment: and according to Apple, i cannot use boot camp if I have the 3tb fusion drive.  see here:  https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209057

Comment: For a time I broke the Fusion drive up into its two separate drives, what a pain that was, the operating system complained about it, a lot. But I was able to use Bootcamp, that is until I gave up and went back to a Fusion drive and only use Windows in Parallels now. It should work fine if you remove the second drive entirely from the computer.

Comment: Like I said - *hardware compatibility.*  You referenced a *very specific* drive.  In other words, does it work with a 2TB?

Comment: Ok, let me be more specific!  If I changed out the current 3tb hard drive (which bootcamp says it will not work with it on my computer) with an SSD, 2tb drive, would Mac OS let me use Boot Camp to run windows 10 on it?

Comment: Short answer...yes.  I have it working with a 1TB all SSD fusion drive and a 1.5TB all SSD fusion TB.  I can't see why it won't work with a 2TB drive (SSD or spinning) as well.

Comment: @DavidAnderson - interesting.  How does that have *anything* to do with the actual question?